# Can a concentration of home offices be "intensive"?

Tags: word-choice

> The New York metropolitan area has the most *intensive concentration of home offices* in the nation, with 17 percent of its households operating a business from home. (The New York Times)

After having read the Merriam-Webster dictionary, I cannot find a definition of "intensive" that explains how this word is used in the sentence above.

Is it proper English to use this adjective (intensive) in that context? As a learner, I thought that "high" is more proper, but, as usual, I'm unsure.

Comment: From [Google's definition](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+intensive&aq=f&oq=define+intensive&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.4379j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=intensive&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=ov9yUavENYjP0AXJ4oHYCg&ved=0CDMQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45512109,d.d2k&fp=350f1be9dcd73e69&biw=1275&bih=922) ***intensive:** Concentrated **on a single area** or subject or into a short time.* It would probably have been better to use ***intense***, but let's not split hairs here. It's valid enough - but like OP, I'd much prefer ***highest*** rather than ***most intens[iv]e***.

Comment: @Fumble, but if "intensive" means "concentrated on a single area", don't you see a sloppy redundance in "intensive concentration"?

Comment: @ Carlo: Not really. There's nothing inherently wrong with redundancy in English anyway. And it's worth pointing out that semantically it wouldn't make any difference if it had just been *has the most concentration of home offices*. It's just that grammatically we don't like that version much. And once he's committed to using the word "most", the writer is a bit stuck for what to put before "concentration". I think actually he ended up with the second-best of a bad bunch.

Comment: He should have backed off "most" and gone with "the highest concentration", probably.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments tell you, *intensive* is an awkward and possibly redundant choice, but not an incorrect one, either formally or semantically.

Most commenters prefer *highest* with *concentration*:

> The New York metropolitan area has the *highest* concentration of home offices in the nation.